# c# program error in sql syntax

Tags: c#, mysql

i am trying to create a program that returns an array of value from a mysql database(db). The program will receive user input and it will be split into substrings, after that the substrings will be compared to the db and it will return an array of values. However I still couldn't get it to work properly. Is there something wrong with my loop function or maybe the label?
here is the program code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace jawiFin
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=971476");

        MySqlCommand mcd;
        MySqlDataReader mdr;
        string s;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string strValue = textBox1.Text;
            string[] strArray = strValue.Split(',',' ');
            foreach (object obj in strArray)
            {
                myConn.Open();

                s = "select * from database01.employeeinfo where name='" + this.textBox1.Text + "';";
                mcd = new MySqlCommand(s, myConn);
                mdr = mcd.ExecuteReader();
                if (mdr.Read())
                {

                        trans.Text += mdr.GetString("surname");

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("error");
                }
                mdr.Close();
                myConn.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it doing that it shouldn't, or not doing that it should?

Comment: First thing to do - use parameterized SQL instead of putting the value directly into your SQL. Next, tell us what's wrong rather than "I still couldn't get it to work properly" - what happens? What did you expect to happen? (I'd suggest you should avoid doing multiple SQL queries, but that can be fixed later.)

Comment: my crystal ball says you are trying to pass a list of names in to your select. this is difficult. you need to make a special database object or use xml

Comment: This is the kind of code that should never be written.  Read about SQL Injection.  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: don't listen to these guys about sql injection. it virtualy never happens!\''drop tables;

Answer (score 3):

Imagine that `this.textBox1.Text` contains a name with an apostrophe, say, `O'Connor`. Now your SQL has syntax error:

```
select * from database01.employeeinfo where name='O'Connor'
--                                                  ^^^^^^^
```

This, however, is rather innocent; think what would happen if name were

```
bobby';delete database01.employeeinfo;--
```

See how this deletes your `employeeinfo` table? This is called SQL Injection attack. Don't do that! Use parameterized SQL statements instead:

```
s = "select * from database01.employeeinfo where name=@name";
mcd = new MySqlCommand(s, myConn);
mcd.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.String);
mcd.Parameters["@name"].Value = this.textBox1.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me, without knowing what you consider wrong, as if this is likely your problem:

This code:

```
   s = "select * from database01.employeeinfo where name='" + this.textBox1.Text + "';";
```

... should actually be this:

```
   s = "select * from database01.employeeinfo where name='" + ((string) obj ) + "';";
```

Incidentally, there are some other mistakes in your code, such as making `obj` an `object` when you already know it's going to be a `string`.

Comment: I got it to work using your advice. thanks a lot Ann.L you are a life saver! Thank you and thank you so very much

Comment: @jenan  You're welcome!  If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as your accepted answer.  Thanks!